# Deploy IVY resolved war file to eclipse tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I am trying to understand whether it is possible to have an eclipse tomcat runtime configuration that will publish the IVY resolved war files when tomcat is started?

I have created a tomcat server instance in eclipse and pointed it at a catalina configuration which includes a server.xml that specifies the contexts.  For example.

```
  <Context docBase="Module1" path="/Module1"/>
```

Module1 is a resolved war file and I have added the corresponding ivy.xml file to the eclipse tomcat classpath.  I can see the war file has been resolved, but I assume I must have to do something extra to get the war files auto deployed on server startup?

Comment: Any particular reason you need ivy? Since war files are standalone, containing all dependencies inside, you could simply use something like "curl" or "wget" to download the file from your Maven repository manager

Comment: IVY is used heavily throughout the project and as a result all resolution of artifacts is done using the IVYde eclipse plugin.   Would rather not have to introduce another process to do this.

Could potentially write a post resolve IVY task which copies the war out of the local IVY cache to the tomcat installation directory.  Not sure if that would work.